# Is it possible to setup vue-chartjs 3.5.1 with momentjs for formatting dates in chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, chart.js, momentjs

I am using `chart.js@2.9.4` through `vue-chartjs@3.5.1` and I am trying to do some date formatting through the options using something like this:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [ {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'full',
        displayFormats: {
          'full': 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

but it does not work. My understanding is that it requires `moment.js` or `chartjs-adapter-moment` but as `vue-chartjs` is a third-party library I can't change it and I don't see an option in the docs for including `moment.js`. Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

I tried the following:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import adapter from 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
Chart.plugins.register(adapter);

import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
```

as well as this:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
```

but it did not help.

EDIT 2:

tried this as well:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import adapter from 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
Chart.register(adapter);

import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
```

as well as adding the following to the `BaseCharts.js` from `vue-chartjs` inside the `node-modules` folder after the `Chart` import:

```
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment'
```

but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

We are using `vue-chartjs` and `chartjs-adapter-luxon` together without issues. Our Vue app has a module which imports ChartJS to register all the features we use, and it imports the luxon adapter.
I don't use moment.js, but I assume it can be registered similarly.

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Filler,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
// and more
} from 'chart.js'
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon'

ChartJS.register(
  Filler,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  ... // and more 
)
```

Comment: Tried this it does not work.

Comment: @PetarVasilev are you using the correct version of the plugin? From the [website](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment): Requires Chart.js 3.0.0 or later and Moment.js 2.0.0 or later. To use Chart.js v2.x, utilize v0.1.2 of the adapter.

Comment: Yes, I am using `0.1.2`.